# Making simple CSS cross-platform

Tags: css, google-chrome

Can anyone help me make this Chrome CSS code cross platform? It doesn't work properly in Firefox or at all in IE8. I really appreciate the help, thanks for reading.

```
.revision-span-in {
    opacity: 0;
}
.revision-span:not(.revision-span-out) {
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
}
.revision-span-out {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

EDIT - Here is the page with the code suggested below, where the issue persists in Firefox. All text on the page should fade in at intervals, but sometimes random parts are appearing without the fade. If it works fine the first time, try refreshing and you'll see what I mean. The page is an output from Twine, and the modified CSS is right at the bottom. Thanks again.

[Example HTML page with inconsistent fade ins in Firefox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/76sl6c3xhl3ch1e/timedexample.html)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to throw some browser vendor-prefixes in there.

Based on the [**current support**](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) of `transition`, you just need `-webkit`, `-moz`, and `-o`:

```
.revision-span-in {
    opacity: 0;
}
.revision-span:not(.revision-span-out) {
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
}
.revision-span-out {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

You won't have support in IE9 and lower.

Comment: I really appreciate the help! I don't know why, but the text fading in only works some of the time in Firefox (I was told elsewhere this was because the code was for Chrome). The CSS is being used in a Twine game, so I suppose its possible the problem is caused elsewhere. Would you say the code you posted should work 100% of the time? Thanks again.

Comment: @user3138070 There is no reason it shouldn't work all the time. Do you have an example demonstrating it not working? Perhaps some CSS is being cached or something...? Or maybe there is some JS interfering with it..

Comment: I've linked the example in the OC. Maybe the modified code is clashing with Twine's built in CSS? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for these experimental features (so in general, if you're not sure about it, look it up) it's best to look up if it's supported by the browser. Since transitions are not completely supported by all major browsers, you need to add the prefix for all browsers that don't fully support it yet. So, according to [MDN's Browser support list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Browser_compatibility), and [Statcounter's browser usage stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201309-201311), you should have the following:

```
.revision-span-in {
    opacity: 0;
}
.revision-span:not(.revision-span-out) {
    transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
}
.revision-span-out {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Since <del>both webkit browsers don't have a generally used version that doesn't fully support it without prefix, and</del> firefox doesn't need a prefix, this should work. The problem you're having shows that you've not updated your firefox in a while, and if you're going to test how your site looks in other browsers, I strongly suggest making sure you've got the up-to-date version. Firefox already supports the syntax without `-moz-` prefix since version 16, and it's at version 26 now (with 25 being the most commonly used at the moment).

Of course if you *really* want to support even the browsers that almost nobody even uses anymore due to automatic updating (such as Firefox <16), you should indeed like <del>Zach Saucier *(deleted his answer)*</del> JoshC says also include the `-moz-` prefix. The `-ms-` prefix is not needed at all though, since every version of IE that does support transitions also supports it without needing that prefix.

EDIT: added `-webkit-` for [Android/Blackberry default browser](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions).

---

## Extra bit (after seeing added dropbox link)

Considering the dropbox link, what I think is causing it is this: Firefox is still animating the first element when the second shows up, so it doesn't restart the animation.

This could explain why it happens randomly: it only happens when Firefox has a few milliseconds of lag, and firefox continues playing the animation for the second item from the starting point of the second animation. This is likely caused by the fact that your items are nested, so the animation of the first row would be inherited by the animation of the second row, and so forth.

Since your animation length is 0.5 seconds exactly, and the interval between showing elements is also 0.5 seconds exactly, if there is the slightest bit of lag this cause these problems. I suggest putting a tiny extra space between showing each element (perhaps 10 or 50ms or so), or changing the items from a nested method to a sibling method. So, instead of this:

```
<div class="body content">
  <span class="first">500ms
    <span class="second">500ms
      <span class="third">500ms
        <span class="fourth">500ms</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Use this:

```
<div class="body content">
  <span class="first">500ms</span>
  <span class="second">500ms</span>
  <span class="third">500ms</span>
  <span class="fourth">500ms</span>
</div>
```

So, instead of appending the spans to the current span, append it to the parent element `.body.content`. I would give you a demo, but your script looks really quite complicated (probably because it's generated by something), so you'll have to try doing that yourself. You could also try putting a tiny bit of extra space between each item's animation starts and see if that fixes it.

Comment: 1+ I think `-ms` was just used for the pre-released version of IE9 - not positive though... it's just a little odd given that `-ms` is needed for CSS transforms in IE9.. http://caniuse.com/transforms2d .. I don't really think it's needed for anything else.

Comment: Firefox is up to date, I just checked. I've linked an example page in the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshC I've added -ms- to the code. I didn't see it at that page, and it's not mentioned at all on MDN.

Comment: @joeytje50 No, I'm just re-confirming the fact that you *don't* need `-ms`. You were right, you don't need that in the code. The only property that needs `-ms` is transform. See this: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: @user3138070 That does indeed look weird. It looks like that's more of a bug than it is incorrect code. I've had a same thing happen in Opera for [This mineturtle I made](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19218989/mineturtle.html), where the mouth animation only plays once. Perhaps this is a common bug for CSS animations where the animation doesn't play again (or in your case, it only plays after a while).

Comment: @JoshC which is probably why I didn't see it the first time ;) Sorry, I am derping a bit here. Fixed it again though.

Comment: @Joeytje50 It's not a delay on the fade-in, its that the fade in sometimes doesn't happen at all, and not always in the same places. Its odd that the error is not consistent.

Comment: @user3138070 I've added a whole new section considering your dropbox link and its buggy behaviour. You might want to try that.

Comment: @joeytje50 You're a genius! I couldn't actually implement your code as the output program will just overwrite what I do each time I compile, but adding an extra 10ms gap after each intended gap means it all works perfectly, so it is just Firefox CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once again I am going to tell you that css3 is still work in progress.So if you want to invoke the css rules then use the vendor prefix provided by their browsers.Note that Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the transition property.

```
-moz-          for firefox use 
-webkit-       for safari and chrome because both uses the same browser engines
-ms-           for microsoft
-o-            for opera

.revision-span-in {
    opacity: 0;
}
.revision-span:not(.revision-span-out) {
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;/*for chrome and safari*/
    -moz-transition: 1s;/*for firefox*/
    -ms-transition: 1s;/*for ie*/
    -o-transition: 1s;/*for opera*/
     transition: 1s;
}
.revision-span-out {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
```